# MongoDB items aren't displaying at all

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**This is the code in my contact.html file**

```
<template name="page1">
  <div id="barHead" class="bar bar-header">
    <button class="button button-clear">Back</button>
    <div class="h1 title">Contacts</div>
    <button class="button button-clear button-positive">Add</button>
  </div><br>
  <div id="contactList">
    {{> conts}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="conts">
  <ul class="list-group">
    {{#each Contacts}}
      {{> aCont}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="aCont">
  <li class="list-group-item">{{this.lastname}}, {{this.firstname}}</li>
</template>
```

**This is my relevant JS code...**

**models.js**

```
Contacts = new Mongo.Collection("contacts");
```

**contact.js**

```
Template.contacts.helpers({
  contacts: function() {
    return Contacts.find({}, {sort: {lastname: -1}, limit: 10});
  },
});
```

**startup.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if(Contacts.find().count() === 0){
        Contacts.insert({firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe", address:"43 Wallaby Way"});
       }
    });
```

Why is it only displaying my header bar and not a contact?

Comment: how are you connecting to mongodb?

Comment: @JoseM I'm using Nitrous.io as my IDE and I'm connecting to mongo through the command line.

Comment: Assuming there is no syntax error, I would first check the connection in the command line using meteor mongo [--url] [site], then check that the document was created in the collection by using db.contacts.find(). If it is there, then check your query and so on.

Comment: @JoseM Thanks for your help I solved the problem. It was a small syntax error ;)